# Images is not copied upon transferring a form in access to another access file

Tags: ms-access

I was transferring my access forms from ms access with .accdb extension to another access file with a .mdb extension. Upon looking over the transferred form, the images embedded on the form is not there anymore. I think it's because the referred images is not copied from the **Image Gallery** of the .acccdb access file.

Any idea how can i copy all the images from image gallery from the .accdb access file to .mdb access.

Comment: There's an option to import images as well when selecting the objects. You might need to click the options button to see those additional options.

Comment: But where can I find those options?

Comment: How do you import the database?

Comment: I just copy a specific form and pasted it to it's destination.

Comment: You shouldn't do it like this. Open the new database, External Data, Access, browse and select the old database with options to import individual objects (forms, queries, modules etc) and images, relationships etc.

Comment: Yeah. The same case still.